# Security identifier "directory" crashes my program

Tags: c, winapi, windows-7

It fails only at the system volumine.

```
#ifndef UNICODE 
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void EndWithBackslash(TCHAR* string)
{
    if(string[wcslen(string)-1] != TEXT('\\')) wcscat(string,TEXT("\\"));
}


void Browse(const TCHAR* curdir)
{
    HANDLE hFoundFile;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA foundFileData;
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];

    wcscpy(buffer,curdir);

    EndWithBackslash(buffer);

    SetCurrentDirectory(buffer);

    hFoundFile = FindFirstFileEx(TEXT("*"),FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS::FindExInfoBasic,&foundFileData ,FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS::FindExSearchLimitToDirectories ,NULL , NULL);

    if(hFoundFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if ((foundFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) && wcscmp(foundFileData.cFileName,TEXT(".")) && wcscmp(foundFileData.cFileName,TEXT("..")) )
            {   
                 TCHAR pszItemPath[MAX_PATH];
                 wcscpy(pszItemPath, buffer);


                EndWithBackslash(pszItemPath);
                wcscat(pszItemPath,foundFileData.cFileName);
                wprintf(TEXT("%s\n"),pszItemPath);

                Browse(pszItemPath);
            }
        }
        while(FindNextFile(hFoundFile,&foundFileData));     
    }
    FindClose(hFoundFile);
}

int main(void) 
{   
    _wsystem(TEXT("chcp 65001"));
    Browse(TEXT("C:\\"));

    _wsystem(TEXT("Pause"));
    return 0;
}
```

The last lines of output, just before run-time error:

> C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5
>   \S-1-5-20
>   C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5
>   \S-1-5-20
>   C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5-20\S-1-5
>   \S-1-5-20

Is there any elegant way to fix it? I would like to avoid deleting this pseudo-directory([Super Users have explained it very well](https://superuser.com/questions/471821/mysterious-folder-next-to-the-recycle-bin))  or setting name filters inside my algorithm.

Comment: Do you check the value returned from `SetCurrentDirectory` by any chance?

Comment: As I [wrote you yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334043/traversing-directories-recursivelly-using-findfirstfileex-function), use of `SetCurrentDirectory` makes your code highly sensible to various issues. It is so much safer to use absolute paths instead. That is, arguments like this in `FindFirstFile` API: `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-20\*.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te crash is caused by a stack overflow error because the `SetCurrentDirectory` failed to change the current directory. As *[Roman R.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/868014/roman-r)* stated, you'll need to check the result of `SetCurrentDirectory`. Moreover, the `.` and `..` subdirectories shouldn't be processed as they refer to the current directory, and the parent directory. Including them in the process would also cause a stack overflow error.

Here's the fixed `Browse` function.

```
void Browse(const TCHAR* curdir)
{
    HANDLE hFoundFile;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA foundFileData;
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];

    wcscpy(buffer,curdir);

    EndWithBackslash(buffer);

    if (!SetCurrentDirectory(buffer)) return;

    hFoundFile = FindFirstFileEx(TEXT("*"),FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS::FindExInfoBasic,&foundFileData ,FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS::FindExSearchLimitToDirectories ,NULL , NULL);

    if(hFoundFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if ((foundFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) && (!wcscmp(foundFileData.cFileName,TEXT("."))) && (!wcscmp(foundFileData.cFileName,TEXT(".."))) )
            {   
                 TCHAR pszItemPath[MAX_PATH];
                 wcscpy(pszItemPath, buffer);


                EndWithBackslash(pszItemPath);
                wcscat(pszItemPath,foundFileData.cFileName);
                wprintf(TEXT("%s\n"),pszItemPath);

                Browse(pszItemPath);
            }
        }
        while(FindNextFile(hFoundFile,&foundFileData));     
    }
    FindClose(hFoundFile);
}
```